# Compilation error while building project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i was working with an android application with uses the jar files of two other project that are present in my eclipse workspace! the android application is api level 16 android 4.1.2. Just before compilation i upgraded android sdk through android sdk manager making all available updates i think necessary. After that The eclipse console gives following errors on compiling application as android project:

```
[2012-12-14 01:51:18 - OcrServiceSampleApp] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-12-14 01:51:18 - OcrServiceSampleApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2012-12-14 01:56:55 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 01:56:55 - OcrServiceSampleApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 02:01:57 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 02:01:57 - OcrServiceSampleApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 02:07:56 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 02:07:56 - OcrServiceSampleApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 02:17:04 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 02:17:04 - OcrServiceSampleApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 02:17:51 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
[2012-12-14 02:17:51 - OcrServiceSampleApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmicrosoft/hawaii/hawaiiClientLibraryBase/ConditionalCompilation;
```

I looked over stack overflow trying following solutions seeing other posts:

-Cleaned my project.

-Deleted my project from workspace added again and then cleaning again.

-deleting dexed libs from the bin folder and then cleaning project again.

-deleting external jars. android jar too. and then using project fix and then cleaning again.

But still am unable to resolve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty project, add the librarie/jar that you are trying to use, so export the empty project and see what happens.

So you will discover where is the problem.